# Best approach to component/visual inheritance in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, inheritance, angular2-directives

I am new to Angular in general and starting in earnest with Angular 2, so I want to find out if I'm not thinking about this in the right way yet.

A "panel" is a page of content in my application.  I'd like to use a base panel component to provide common UI and functionality to specific panel implementations that derive from it.

I'd like for the base panel component to have templated content that wraps the template provided by the derived component- this would, for instance, provide a standardized header whose content is provided by the derived implementation and allow for the child component to supply the page content itself.

The ultimate goal is to make it as easy as possible for developers to create new panels without having to worry about rendering the common parts, so that consistency can be enforced.

Also, I want for the developer to be able have two-way binding between base variables/properties that are programmatically set from the derived component and the corresponding elements that are rendered by the parent template... (in addition to the elements in their own child template).

Is this doable?  Or am I thinking about this in the wrong way... not sure if I'm in an Angular state-of-mind yet.

As I've been working on this, I'm starting to think I may need to adjust to creating reusable components (like PanelHeaderComponent) that the developer would compose within their panel implementation rather than inheriting from a base for common UI... However, I do need for the container for all panels to be centrally managed somehow.

Want to be sure I do this the right way.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe a valid approach is, like you said in your last paragraphs, to componentize your application.

Basically: Create reusable components for the different parts of your application (ie: Panel Header with Buttons with a certain style)

If you want different panels that will use the same header, you can then reuse that Panel Header in all of your your panels.

It would be analogous regarding buttons, and any other control that you want to use. Define your component, then reuse it everywhere, then reuse the reusable, composite components that you defined.

**Important Note:** As of now, and as far as I'm aware, there's no Visual Inheritance between components, so in order to simplify your job, you might want to use sass to define the styles and take advantage of @imports in order to DRY.